# Argument type error with Spring AMQP receiver

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

My Spring AMQP application has been logging the following exception on initiation:

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Failed to invoke target method 'receiveMessage' with argument type = [class [B], value = [{[B@660cff44}]
```

From my searching I understand that this is because there is a class incompatibility with the message type?  However, I am not able to see where this is.

The following are the relevant code segments:

```
@Bean
public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter(){
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}

@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(config.getAMQPResultsQueue(), false);
}

@Bean
TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange(config.getAMQPResultsExchange());
}

@Bean
Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with("#");
}

@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(config.getAMQPResultsQueue());
    container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
    container.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    return container;
}

@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class Receiver {
    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">");
    }
}
```

I have tried setting the class of message to Byte[] but the result is the same.  I am sure I am missing something simple - just not sure what it is!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` will only perform conversion if the message has a `content_type` header that contains `json`.

Otherwise, it will return `byte[]`.

`byte[]` will also not be converted to `Byte[]`. Set the header or use `byte[]`.

Comment: Thank you for this, however the exception seems to be thrown when the application starts - not when it receives messages - I guess it is possible that a message is already in the queue - will check

Comment: This seems to have solved the issue.  I just wanted to say how appreciative I am that developers such as yourself take the time to assist others in the way that you do.  It is incredibly generous.

Comment: I stumbled accross this problem recently and this answer is not 100% correct as  `content_type` has to be specified as message property and not message header.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue when I set the property in RabbitMQ interface to `content-type` (understandably, since that's how the http spec spells it). But RabbitMQ has it underscored. `content_type` is the name of the property you would have to set in RabbitMQ interface to publish a message with HTTP Header `Content-Type`

Comment: I second that. The message must include a parameter with the name 'content_type', with the underscore, and its value must be set correctly, e.g. 'applicatoin/json' or 'text/plain'. SimpleMessageConverter in Spring  relies on this parameter to convert the body's raw bytes to a string. If the payload remains unconverted, i.e. byte[], and there is no @RabbitHandler method that takes a byte array, this exception will be thrown: NoSuchMethodException: No listener method found in /a_classname/ for class [B